# I need help using Regex or any other way to solve my address problem

Tags: c#

In this problem, I have a string with an address; however, it could not be formatted perfectly. In my example I have
string candidate = "20-54 Jackson Avenue Date) Brooklyn, NY 11352"
The reason it's like this is because it was read in from a pdf that has columns so it read it left to right. Right now I am currently using this regex:

```
 var reg = Regex.Match(candidate, 
           @"^(\d*-?\d*\s)([N|S|W|E]\s)?([A-z]*((\s[A-z]*)?))\s([A-z]*)\s([A-z]*(\s)?(([A-z]*)?),)");//(\s[A-z]*\s)(\d*)");
```

I believe the reason it's not working is because of the ')' after Date. I need to store the Address, City, State, and Zip code individually in separate variable. I have used the usual `string addypractice = reg.Groups[0].Value;` but because of the left parenthesis its always coming up null. Does anyone have any advice on how to deal with this or have an easier way to solve my problem? thank you!!

Comment: Try this regex. It gives you the individual tokens of your string. `([a-zA-z0-9]+)(?!>\))`  Example: https://regex101.com/r/7HUc9H/1

Comment: How would I access each token to store it inside the variable? Also how would I make it broad enough to do this for each possible address? An address could have a single street name like Smith St. or could have more like Water Circle Way. Same thing with cities: New York compared to Albany

Comment: I think you should explain in more detail what the actual problem is that you want to solve and add some more examples of valid and invalid values. Maybe by means of another regex101 snippet.

Comment: I need to make a function which is passed in a string that carries an address. The address could be formatted correctly or carry weird characters in the middle of it. I'm supposed to parse the string and extract the Address (Number, Street Name and Street Abbreviation), the City, the State and the zip code. Here is another string that gets passed in but is normally formatted: 595 Park Avenue New York, NY 10021

Comment: The only problem is Rahul that I don't know what cases I have. The user will input files and a different folder will extract the addresses, so I have no idea which file I get or how it's formatted

Comment: Check this regex for the original input string asked in the question: `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[^\),\d{5}]*` Working Example: https://regex101.com/r/7HUc9H/3. If there are more scenarios, then you would have to handle them accordingly.

Comment: Okay, then it is going to be tricky since we don't know what the format of the string would be. You would have to start with some pattern for certain strings that you expect and then work your way around with that. Once you see a pattern, you can write different regex's to parse those strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solely based on the input string given in the question:

Regex:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[^!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>,\d{5}]*
```

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/7HUc9H/4

This regex takes into account other scenarios where there are special characters before your address:

For example, strings like:

- 20-54 Jackson Avenue Date" Brooklyn, NY 11352
- 20-54 Jackson Avenue Date} Brooklyn, NY 11352
- 20-54 Jackson Avenue Date* Brooklyn, NY 11352

will also be parsed by this regex. You could even add more character classes to this regex based on your requirement.

**Edit:**

C# code to read your string and the match with the above regex to get your desired result:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Test1
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "20-54 Jackson Avenue Date) Brooklyn, NY 11352";
            string[] result =Regex.Matches(str, "[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[^!@#$%^&*(),.?\":{}|<>,\\d{5}]*").Cast<Match>().Select(x=>x.Value).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("Address:"+result[0].Trim());
            Console.WriteLine("City:"+result[1].Trim());
            Console.WriteLine("State:"+result[2].Trim());
            Console.WriteLine("Zip Code:"+result[3].Trim());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I was just wondering how I would access each piece of information since they're all in the same group.

Comment: Updated my answer with C# code to read your string and use the regex in the answer to parse out your information.

Comment: You're a life saver man!! Just one little thing left. I'm sorry if I'm being annoying. I've tried messing around with the regex, but how would I ignore any information after the Zip Code? like say the string is "1234 S Mary Dr New York, NY 10234 aoerngieron"

Comment: Nvm I got it!! Thank you so much for your help!!